# Inject dynamic script in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I'm doing an extension now and i have one part of script which is static (will never change) and another part which is loaded from the website. And, i'm seeing 2 ways:

1. To load it with XMLHttpRequest and inject into web page
2. To put it as a `<script src="example.com/myscript.js"></script>` and have it load it itself

But, the second way probably won't have access to my extension API (to functions defined in extension files, i.e. in `chrome://myext/script.js`)

And, the first way will probably be unsecure because i will have to eval the code in a `gBrowser.contentWindow.wrappedJSObject` object which is a Window object for the loaded page

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want the dynamic script to have chrome privileges? If so, why not load it using XMLHttpRequest, save it to disk and then import it as a JavaScript Module (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using). Obviously there are security considerations since you are giving a script from the web pretty much unlimited privileged, but if you control the script's source then you are presumably okay. If you are really worried you can use HTTPS to download the script, which will protect against someone intercepting the traffic.

If you want the code to run with content privileges but have access to functions in your chrome JavaScript, then maybe you want to expose the chrome functions to content as described in this article: http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/weirdal/archives/017188.html

Comment: ahh i see, so there is a possibility to save to disk? do you know of any?

Comment: also, i need this script to be injected in each loaded page, but i think `Components.utils.import` imports the script in xul, not in inner page

Comment: Okay, I added a new suggestion to the original answer since I think I understand better now what you are trying to do.

Comment: very interesting, Firefox has the whole other approach on addons, not like Chrome at all - in chrome it's a "HTML pages with Browser APIs" while in Firefox it's something like "JS APIs with access to HTML"